# Update charge field after stripe charge is processed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm using the stripe gem, and followed the very basic setup to charge a card. I am trying to have a field in my database changed when the charge has been successfully processed. The below code is not updating the :charge (boolean type) field of my database to 1.

After the processing has succeeded it redirects a user to the create.html.erb, but I to redirect them to a different path, but haven't been able to successfully find out how to do that.

Thanks Stack!

Charges controller:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
def index
end

def new

end

def create

    @event = Event.find(session[:event_id])

    #Amount in cents
    @amount = 199

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => "user email",
        :card => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer => customer.id,
        :amount => @amount,
        :description => 'description',
        :currency => 'usd'
    )

    @event[:charge] == 1

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to charges_path
end
end
```

New.html.erb:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">Event Information</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Image Upload</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Verify Details</a></li>
  <li class="active">Pay</li>
</ul>

<%= form_tag charges_path do %>
<article>
    <label class="amount">
        <span>Amount: $1.99</span>
    </label>
</article>

<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
        data-description="description"
        data-amount="199"></script>
<% end %>
```

Create.html.erb

```
<h2>Thanks, you paid <strong>$1.99</strong>!</h2>
```

Comment: It's not updating your database because you are not saving it. Do this instead: `@event.update_attributes(charge: true)`

Comment: Thanks! I should have realized I wasn't saving the attribute. I didn't know I could use that syntax for updating also.

Any clue on the redirect?

Comment: Just use `redirect_to` and the path you want it to go to. You know how to do that since you did it in the rescue.